# Accessing USB avermedia DVBT Dongle A867

Tags: usb-drive, dvb

I have a usb dvbt dongle that I want to connect to our STB. I could build and insert the modules but then want to acquire the TS and pump that to vendor sw for demux and decoding. How to grab the TS buffer or data from the avermedia device?

Comment: Assuming that it is seen by the kernel as a DVB device, the `dvbsrc` element for GStreamer should work.

Comment: thanks for response. I cannot use gstreamer or directfb. Yes the device is recognized as dvb device. I could tune the device to particular frequency usinf /dev/frontend but then want to pump the TS data form the demod directly to our proprietary driver sw which takes care in parsing/scanning the TS.